# About the nature of acceleration and velocity given a vector trajectory

Tags: vector-analysis

Ok, it's a simple question, i'm studying for a test and I am given a vector $\vec{r}(t)=<t^2-5t,2t+1,3t^2>$, and asked to determine the points where it's acceleration and velocity are orthogonal. 
Simple enough, but I ran into a problem. I thought I could compute it in two ways, either:$$\vec{v}=\vec{r'}\\\vec{a}=\vec{r''}$$ and then do $\vec{a}\cdot{\vec{v}}=0$, which apparently did not work, or use the formulas for the acceleration with $$\vec{v}=\vec{r'}\\\vec{a}=v'.\vec{T}+[v^2/\rho].\vec{N}$$and compute the same dot product. I do understand that $d\vec{v}/dt=d[v.\vec{T}]/dt$ and that requires you to use the chain rule to get to the second expression of the acceleration I proposed, but I don't quite see why doing my first approach should yield the wrong result.
So, thats it: what make the first approach wrong, and the second right?

Comment: Your first idea seems reasonable to me, why did it not work?

Comment: Well, doing it i get that the points are when $t=1/4$ which, according to the answer of the booklet I have, is wrong. It should be $t=10/38$. I didn't compute the second approach because it is a lot longer and unless i understood why I had to use it I saw no use in crunching the numbers, but I am guessing it will yield the right result.

Comment: Have you checked your calculations?

Comment: Yeah: $\vec{r'}=<2t-5,2,6t>$, $\vec{r''}=<2,0,6>$, $\vec{r'}\cdot\vec{r''}=4t-10+36t$, and finally $t=1/4$ (P.s.: I apologize, $\vec{r}$ was written wrong in the post, really sorry about that)

Comment: $\mathbf{a\cdot v}=0$ gives zero instantaneous power, not zero work.

Comment: well, it might be the answer is just wrong in the booklet, anyways. I was convinced that it was right the way I did, if you are also convinced, maybe it IS actually right.

Comment: @NgChungTak Sorry, what?

Comment: $\text{Work done}=\int \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r}$,$\text{ Power}=\mathbf{F\cdot v}$

Comment: But what does this have to do with what was asked? I have a mathematical trajectory and want to know the points where it's acceleration and velocitys are perpendicular. I don't even have a force field to work with.

Comment: You mean $\mathbf{a\cdot v}$ did not work or did no work (zero work)?

Comment: I said did **not** work, as in didn't compute to the right result. If I wanted to say did zero work, i'd say did **no** work.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
  \mathbf{v} &= (2t-5,2,6t) \\
  \mathbf{a} &= (2,0,6) \\
  \dot{s} &= \sqrt{(2t-5)^2+2^2+(6t)^2} \\
  &= \sqrt{40t^2-20t+29} \\
  \ddot{s} &= \frac{10(4t-1)}{\sqrt{40t^2-20t+29}} \\
\end{align}

> When $t=\dfrac{1}{4}$, $$\ddot{s}=0 \implies \mathbf{a} \perp \mathbf{v}$$

See also [**link 1**](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/310064/question-about-a-v-mathrm-dv-mathrm-dx/310072#310072) and [**link 2**](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/317192/prove-a-force-driven-by-a-cross-product-between-a-vector-and-its-velocity-gives/317272#317272).

Comment: Did you read the post? I didn't want the answer, I wanted to know why my method wasn't working, according to the answer in the book, not the answer to the problem in the exact way I had done it. Anyways, your answer just shows that yes, my answer is probably right, and the answer the book offers is wrong. Furthermore, the links you posted are obviously of no use for me, since I already specified where the equations came from, and that is the exact reason I couldn't understand why my answer wasn't valid. The reason was that it was, in fact, valid.

Comment: I showed that they agree. That is **WORK!!**

Comment: What do you mean by "that is work"?

Comment: Thank you anyway for taking your time to corroborate my answer.

Comment: The tangent vector component vanishes which means $a \perp v$

Comment: I am afraid we might be suffering from a language barrier here then, anyways, no worries, all is settled now. I think you meant "That it works". Yeah, it works, thanks for showing that :)